# Upgrading Database, Downloading APOC, Connectivity, and Upgrading Date Store and Format

Tags: neo4j

I've upgraded a database from neo4j 3.35 to 3.41, using neo4j Desktop. There are four consequential behaviors I don't understand: [Edited to reflect behaviors that have been explained and solved.]

- [Solved with update to Desktop 1.1.7] I can no longer load Neo4j's browser by clicking on the Neo4j Browser Button in Neo4j desktop; I know of no other means. The mouse pointer becomes a circle with a line through it when it's over the button. I can load the database with Chrome.
- [Solved; I was in Offline Mode] I can't download APOC, GRAPH ALGORITHMS, or GraphQL; my mouse pointer aims at the install button, and I'm presented with an orange speech box that reads 'Offline'.
- [Solved; comment at end] When I gave the command to upgrade the graph, I was given the option to automatically migrate the graphdata. I don't understand what this option meant, but it failed when I tried it: 'Graph migration failed. Please try again.' When I declined that option, the upgrade succeeded. [Solved: I had failed to open that database's neo4j.conf file (in conf folder) and un-comment -- remove the # from in front of -- the line that reads dbms.allow_upgrade=true. Thanks to InfiniteFalcon]
- [Solved, see note on previous behavior.] In attempting to map, in the upgraded database, a property to a duration value -- for example, match (n), set n.date = date('2018-07-01') -- I got the following error:

> Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: Current record format does not support TEMPORAL_PROPERTIES. Please upgrade your store to the format that support requested capability.

I'd be grateful for any feedback or direction. Thanks, sincerely.

Comment: Did you add `dbms.allow_upgrade=true` to your neo4j.conf file, then restart neo4j? That should migrate your record format, and is a key part of the upgrade process.

Comment: Well, don't I feel silly. I opened the config file, checked and made sure that dbms.all_upgrade=true was in there, thought it was weird that I didn't need to change anything -- there it was, and totally neglected to notice the # which made it a comment.

Thank you. I apologize for not being better than this. :/

Comment: The only problems that remain regard the behavior of Neo4j Desktop: why would it  prevent me from using the browser, or installing the plugins? With thanks, again, for all attention and help.

Comment: Those often indicate proxy issues.  If you need to configure a proxy to use, click the gear icon on the lower left of the Desktop app, there should be a section to set the proxy.

Comment: I'm not using a proxy; consequently, I'm not sure how I'd go about setting one up on Neo4j. The offline speech box persists with the update to Neo4j Desktop 1.1.7. However, the update has solved the issue with the Neo4j Browser.